# Creating an RSA public key - Rust

Tags: rust, cryptography, rsa

I want to create an RSA public key to secure my messages to server.
When I try to use `RsaPublicKey::new(n, e);`, but i don't know use this.

```rust
use serde_json::{json, Value, Value as JsonValue};
use quick_xml::events::Event;
use quick_xml::reader::Reader;

use rsa::{RsaPublicKey, BigUint};

use crate::crypto::Crypto;
use crate::net::Tcp;


fn json_settings() -> JsonValue {
    let json: Value = json!({
        "key": "0dc-2-7b-98d-94" // censored
    });

    json
}

pub async fn get_key() {

    // Create and send information to the server
    let mut tcp = Tcp::setup_conn().await;
    let _s1 = tcp.send("yu");

    // If server send me ya, we send json_settings, then,
    // the server return public_key far a RSA encryption.
    if _s1 == "ya" {
        let _s2 = tcp.send(&json_settings().to_string()); 
        
        let json_value: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(&_s2).unwrap();
        let xml = json_value["public_key"].as_str().unwrap(); // server response.

        // -start-
        // Here, we retrieve the value from the json response's xml and store it in a list.
        let mut reader = Reader::from_str(xml);
        reader.trim_text(true);

        let mut txt = Vec::new();
        loop {
            match reader.read_event().unwrap() {
                Event::Text(e) => txt.push(e.unescape().unwrap().into_owned()),
                Event::Eof => break,
                _ => (),
            }
        }
        // -end-

        // here I have an encrypt() function, I give it my key as an argument,
        // which must be of type RsaPublicKey, and the given f to encrypt everything.
        Crypto::encrypt(txt[0], b"hello");
        
        println!("{:?}", txt);
    }
}
```

Here is my function for encrypt message with the public key.

```rust
// Encrypt with public key.
pub fn encrypt(pub_key: RsaPublicKey, data: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut rng = OsRng;
    pub_key
       .encrypt(&mut rng, Pkcs1v15Encrypt, data)
       .expect("failed to encrypt")
}
```

And the error, but I know why, I wait just to know how converte my txt[0] (key) to RsaPublicKey, I think I should use `RsaPublicKey::new(n, e);`. (e = exponent & n = part of the public key)

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/script.rs:50:25
   |
50 |         Crypto::encrypt(txt[0], b"hello");
   |         --------------- ^^^^^^ expected `RsaPublicKey`, found `String`
   |         |
   |         arguments to this function are incorrect
```

Comment: Hi there! Next time, please link the doc for the lib(s) you're using, it'll be easier on the reader's end ;) For your question, with some research in the lib I found out that n -> "modulus" and e -> "exponent". I'll let you do your own research about RSA modulus and RSA exponent, but I just have one more pointer to give you, which is here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/35105 I'd advise you to look at the content of your "txt" and see what could resemble to an exponent and a modulus. Except if you define it yourself, in which case you can probably know what is what. Good luck!!

Comment: I think that the important thing missing here is the structure of that `xml` variable you have. It looks like you are flattening all the inner contents of that XML into a the `txt` variable, that sounds a bit fishy...